# Converting an SVG to PNG with React Native and expo

Tags: node.js, react-native

I am trying to convert an SVG string OR a SVG base64 encoded string to a PNG file (preferably base64 encoded).
This would be easy in a web environment, with canvas, or even a node.js environment, with packages like sharp, but in react native, I don't have access to any of these. I have tried searching for solutions, but I couldn't find any. The only solution I see for now would be to send my SVG to an API (created by me) and convert it there, but that's probably inefficient and I don't want to take 2 seconds only on the conversion.

I have tried to use sharp, but as expected it didn't work as it's a package for node.js. React native can't work with it.

Any suggestions or ideas appreciated